# Is there an equivalent IfNull function in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have experience with SQL but not so much with ElasticSearch so forgive me newbieness (is that a word). Is there a way to write a similar query in ElasticSearch:

`select externalid, ifnull(recordingduration, duration)  from calls  where businessid = 995 and calldate between '2023-05-01' and '2023-05-03' order by 2 desc limit 10;`

The "where" clause isn't as important as I know how to do that. I am more interested in the ifnull function along with the ability to sort on it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I looked online and can't find any equivalent to the ifnull function. Basically, if one field is null, I want to get the value of another field and sort the combined value of both. Sorting on one or the other has imperfect results and doing it in the code would require me to get the complete result set.